# Why is external variable out of scope to PHP function?

Tags: php

I have a small problem with a PHP function that can't access a variable that was defined outside its code block and I can't see what the problem is. Redefining the variable inside the function block works fine but seems a superfluous step:

```
<?php
    //constants for database connection
    define(DB_RESOURCE, "192.168.99.67");
    define(DB_USERNAME, "myUsername");
    define(DB_PASSWORD, "p@ssword");
    define(DB_NAME, "myDatabase");
    //variable defined here so why can't function see it?
    $dbConnect = mysqli_connect(DB_RESOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


    function readData($table, $column) {
        $sql = "SELECT {$column} FROM {table}";
        //redefining this solves the problem but why is this needed?
        // $dbConnect = mysqli_connect(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        //the $dbConnect variable is not defined and error is flagged in PHPStorm in the line below
        $data =  mysqli_query($dbConnect, $sql);
    }
?>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Many thanks for your help,

Kw

Comment: `{column}` !== `{$column}`

Comment: Thanks but that (other) error, does not affect the problem which persists!

Comment: [Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)... it's amazing how much reading the PHP Docs can teach about how to write code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php if you want to use any variable inside any function without passing it in parameter. you need to defined it as global. it before using you need `global $dbConnect`.

```
<?php
    //constants for database connection
    define(DB_RESOURCE, "192.168.99.67");
    define(DB_USERNAME, "myUsername");
    define(DB_PASSWORD, "p@ssword");
    define(DB_NAME, "myDatabase");
    //variable defined here so why can't function see it?
    $dbConnect = mysqli_connect(DB_RESOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


    function readData($table, $column) {
        $sql = "SELECT {$column} FROM {table}";
        //redefining this solves the problem but why is this needed?
        global  $dbConnect;
        // now you can use $dbConnect. In php you need to specify it as global once inside the block after it you can use 

        $data =  mysqli_query($dbConnect, $sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

```
global $dbConnect;
```

in your Function. Functions have they own scopes, that means they can only see Varibales wich are defined inside them or globalized with global.

Comment: Using `global` isn't really good; better to pass as an argument to the function

Comment: Mark Baker, thats correct. But he yould have to have $dbConnect everywhere he uses readData wich is maybe a big disadvantage.

Comment: Maybe @Paflow, but in large scale sites the database connection is *typically* included in such a way as to be available to function calls. YMMV

Comment: Many thanks for the advice and helpful comments, all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of [PHP's scoping rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). PHP is not JavaScript. In JavaScript, this will work just fine:

```
var myVar = 12;
alertVar();

function alertVar() {
    alert(myVar);
}
```

This function will run, and the value 12 will be alerted without issue. PHP does not behave like this.  The above function in PHP would look like this:

```
$myVar = 12;
echoVar();

function echoVar() use($myVar) {
    echo $myVar;
}
```

Instead of using the [`use` construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160), you could also just reference the global scope, or the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) super global, or just pass the variable in as a parameter:

```
function echoVar() {
    global $myVar;
    echo $myVar;
}

// or

function echoVar() {
    echo $GLOBALS['myVar'];
}

// or

echoVar($myVar);
function echoVar($var) {
    echo $var;
}
```

Relevant quote from the manual:

> [...] within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope. [...] In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone want to pass the database connection to the function?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'd say that is probably the best call for this simple case, the order of options in my answer makes no distinction on which way is 'best'. I leave it to OP to decide which of these options would work best for them. I showed the `use` example first, because in my mind it is the closest in form to the JavaScript example I gave to highlight the differences between function scope in JavaScript/PHP

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the database connection to the function:

```
<?php
    //constants for database connection
    define(DB_RESOURCE, "192.168.99.67");
    define(DB_USERNAME, "myUsername");
    define(DB_PASSWORD, "p@ssword");
    define(DB_NAME, "myDatabase");

    $dbConnect = mysqli_connect(DB_RESOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


    function readData($table, $column, $dbConnect) {
        $sql = "SELECT {$column} FROM {$table}";
        $data =  mysqli_query($dbConnect, $sql);
        // additional code here...
    }

    readData('table_name', 'column_name', $dbConnect);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, another good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is absolutely correct. Just enclose all that code inside a class.

Example:

```
class YourClassName{

  //constants for database connection
  define(DB_RESOURCE, "192.168.99.67");
  define(DB_USERNAME, "myUsername");
  define(DB_PASSWORD, "p@ssword");
  define(DB_NAME, "myDatabase");

  //variable defined here so why can't function see it?
  $dbConnect = mysqli_connect(DB_RESOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


  function readData($table, $column) {
    $sql = "SELECT {$column} FROM {table}";
    //redefining this solves the problem but why is this needed?
    global  $dbConnect;
    // now you can use $dbConnect. In php you need to specify it as global once inside the block after it you can use 

    $data =  mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sql); //CHANGE THIS LINE AS SHOWN HERE.
  }
}
```